# Installing Wampserver2.0i on Windows Server 2003 but Oracle Server using port 80

Tags: oracle, apache, wampserver, port80, windows-server-2003-r2

I've installed Wampserver2.0i on Windows Server 2003 and I've tested the port 80 using the option from the menu once I clicked the wamp icon in the notification bar and the result from the cmd as the below:

> Server: Oracle HTTP server powered by apache/1.3.22 
>   mod_plsql/3.0.9.8.3b mod_ssl/2.8.5 OpenSSL/0.9.6b mod_fastcgi/2.2.1

The problem is localhost take me to Oracle server not to the www directory!

How can I solve this?

Comment: Just out of interest, why did you install such an old version of WAMPServer?

Comment: As the message says... You already have a web server installed on your system and therefore it is using port 80. Do you still use that very old version of apache for anything?

Comment: yes dear, but I had to in order to run php scripts on the server and it's  an old version because this is the version that just works on windows server 2003, the new versions won't work. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run 2 web servers on the same machine without changing the configuration of one of them. By default all web servers Listen on TCP port 80 and thats the reason you are having problems.

Because the `Oracle HTTP server powered by apache/1.3.22` is probably configured to start automatically it has already captured TCP Port 80 and therefore when you start WAMPServer it cannot get access to port 80, *only one program can use a port at any one time*.

You can change the port number that Apache listens on quite easily, as suggested by bob dylan.
Edit the httpd.conf file and change the config to tell Apache to listen on another port, so using the WAMPManager menus you would do this :-

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf
```

This will open the httpd.conf file in an editor, look for these lines

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

And change them to, for example

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
```

Save the file and then restart Apache

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Restart Service
```

Now Apache will listen on port 8080 so the 2 Apache versions will not conflict with each other.

However this change means that you will have to put the port number on all your URL's like so

```
localhost:8080
localhost:8080/phpmyadmin
```

which can become a bit of a pain after a while.

A simpler solution would be to put WAMPServer on another machine and then there would be no conflict. *Remember WAMPServer is configured to be a development web server and not a LIVE web server*. It should run just fine on your own personal workstation/PC.

Answer (score 1):

In C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf

edit httpd.conf where it says:

```
 Listen 0.0.0.0:80
 Listen [::0]:80
```

Then restart your service

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/diy-it-guy/diy-running-apache-on-a-non-standard-port/

Comment: Can u describe what does this line means ?

Comment: Which line? 0.0.0.0 = local ip. :80 = port.